# Yeoman generator with Babel flow

Tags: node.js, yeoman, ecmascript-6, babeljs, yeoman-generator

I've decided to rewrite my generator from ES5 syntax to ES6. But I faced the issue with transpiling generator on pre-publish.

**Issue**: As we know Yeoman generators have `templates` folder where different files is located. When Babel is traspiling all the generators sources via `babel src --out-dir generators` it skips the templates files or breaks the traspiling with error.

**My Attepmts**: I was trying to make something like `babel src --out-dir generators && cp -rn src/ generators/` but I don't like this solution.

**Question**: How can I make old structure `generators/sub-generators` but in ES6 syntax, not in ES5.

Thanks.

**UPD**: I'm hoping that Yeoman has something like Mocha has `--require babelhook.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this case.

First of all, I've created `src` folder where generator sources in ES6 syntax is located. Structure of this folder is the same as in usual ES5 generator.

When I want to compile these sources I just need to copy them and compile in `generators` folders.

So I've written the following scripts in `package.json`;

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf ./generators",
  "compile": "npm run clean && cp -r src/ generators/ && babel src --out-dir generators",
  "prepublish": "npm run compile",
  "test": "istanbul cover _mocha"
}
```

And last thing that I've done is add `ignore` field in `.babelrc` file. So I'm sure that templates will be just copied but not traspiled.

```
{
  "stage": 0,
  "ignore": [
    "app/templates",
  ]
}
```